# Passing params to nested screens in createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have main drawer navigator with a few nested stack navigators.

I'm initializing the nested stack navigators with default params.
Currently, I'm using the function `dangerouslyGetParent` in the screens of the stack navigator to get the parameters from the drawer.

Is there a way to pass the parameters from the stack navigator to the nested screens?

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
PersonalSettings: {
  screen: PersonalSettingsScreen,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    collectionName: navigation.state.params.collectionName,
  }),
},
```

Thank you from advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use react navigations setParam and getParam functions inside the screen itself
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({collectionName: collectionName})
```

```
this.props.navigation.getParam("collectionName")
```

Comment: I can't use the getParam

Comment: In order to get it work, I'll have to use dangerouslyGetParent.
I would like to avoid from this.